# Is this the right way to terminate subprocess?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, record, terminate

I am using arecord through subprocess to record in raspberry pi : press joystick button to start recording and press button again to stop recording:  I use the p.terminate()  to stop recording, here is my code. i don't know if it is the right way to terminate subprocess?

Thanks in advance.

```
if joystick.get_numbuttons() >= 1 and joystick.get_button( 0 ) == 0 and    button_pressed:
button_pressed = False
is_recording = not is_recording
print(is_recording)

#start recording
if is_recording:
    dotting = dotting + 1
    #recording code
   datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    filename = "%s.wav" % datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    p=subprocess.Popen(['arecord', '--device=hw:1,0', '--format', 'S16_LE', '--rate', '44100-c1', filename], shell=False)

    #change background
    background = pygame.image.load(background_image2).convert()
    #start timer
    stopFlag = Event()
    timer = MyTimer(stopFlag,time.clock())
    #timer.start()
    text2 = font.render('.', True, BLACK)

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    stopFlag.set()

    #record, remaining here


#stop recording
else:
    #stop recording, save record
    timer.do_run = False
    backToPreviousQuestion()
    background = pygame.image.load(background_image).convert()
    p.terminate()
```

pygame.display.update()

Comment: `Popen.terminate()` *is*, in general, the right thing. By the way, for requesting feedback on working code (as opposed to questions about specific problems, with code built into a [mcve] that isolates a single problem), consider [codereview.se] instead of StackOverflow (though *do* read the Help Center there before posting).

Comment: Thank you, i am a noob in programming. I will move to the code review to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking in a general sense, `.terminate()` is the correct method to use to end a subprocess. You can see the documentation for more information: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/

Comment: Thank you, i am a noob in programming. appreciate for your help